# Twilio Quickstart Code for SMS Conversations not incrementing

Tags: ruby, heroku, sms, sinatra, twilio

I'm using labcoder's Twilio-Hackpack-for-Heroku-and-Sinatra then am following the [Ruby Quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby) on Twilio's site.  I've literally copied and pasted the code and it refuses to increment the counter.

The only difference between the quickstart code and my code is I use get_or_post:

```
get_or_post '/sms/?' do
```

Instead of their:

```
get '/sms-quickstart' do
```

When I use their get method with the /sms-quickstart, I get an ERROR (11200) HTTP Retrieval Failure. When I use get_or_post with /sms/?, it works, but my counter will not increment and I just keep getting the same "Hello, thanks for the new message." Here is the code from my app.rb

```
get_or_post '/sms/?' do
  session["counter"] ||= 0
  sms_count = session["counter"]
  if sms_count == 0
    message = "Hello, thanks for the new message."
  else
    message = "Hello, thanks for message number #{sms_count + 1}"
  end
  twiml = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Sms message
  end
  session["counter"] += 1
  twiml.text
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sinatra doesn't enable sessions by default. Need to add the following to app.rb:

```
enable :sessions
```

See documentation [here](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#sessions)